# Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user

Tags: android, shortcut, broadcast

I want to create a shortcut use the code below, but it comes an error and the shorcut can't be created, but i can find other apps has shortcut on the desktops.

Is anywhere wrong?

```
public static void addShortcut(Context cx, int iconResource) {
    Intent shortcut = new Intent(
            "com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    Intent shortcutIntent = cx.getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(cx.getPackageName());
    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    String title = null;
    try {
        final PackageManager pm = cx.getPackageManager();
        title = pm.getApplicationLabel(
                pm.getApplicationInfo(cx.getPackageName(),
                        PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)).toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // The name of shortcut.
    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, title);
    shortcut.putExtra("duplicate", false);
    Parcelable icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(cx,
            iconResource);
    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
    cx.sendBroadcast(shortcut);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot add the permission

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```